# how to change php version in htaccess in server

Tags: php, .htaccess, version

I'm using `php 5.3` on my local machine. On our webserver we have `php 4.8`. Our server is a shared server. So I want to change the php version on our server via `.htaccess` file. Is it possible to do it? If yes how to do it?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

To switch to PHP 4.4:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php4 .php
```

To switch to PHP 5.0:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

To switch to PHP 5.1:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php51 .php
```

To switch to PHP 5.2:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php
```

To switch to PHP 5.3:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php
```

To switch to PHP 5.4:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```

To switch to PHP 5.5:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php
```

To switch to PHP 5.6:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php
```

To switch to PHP 7:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php7 .php
```

To switch to PHP 7.1:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php
```

Comment: when I do this none of my php files are processed correctly. Is there something that you need to add to the .htaccess file before you add these statements?

Comment: `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php7 .php` did _not_ work for me, but `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php` did the job!

Comment: This is a great starting point, but I'll caution you to check with your particular Web host, as some settings can be different. Since I have client sites hosted with different providers, what may work with one won't with another.

Comment: For me this works when i check phpinfo() but not when running php -v, this still shows the old version and so does composer (uses the old version). any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

Note that all above answers are correct for Apache+[mod-php](/questions/tagged/mod-php) setups. They're less likely to work with more current PHP-FPM setups. Those can typically only be defined in VirtualHost section, not .htaccess.

Again, this highly depends on how your hoster has configured PHP. Each domain/user will typically have it's own running PHP FPM instance. And subsequently a generic `…/x-httpd-php52` type will not be recognized.

See [**ServerFault**: Alias a FastCGI proxy protocol handler via Action/ScriptAlias/etc](https://serverfault.com/questions/884781/alias-a-fastcgi-proxy-protocol-handler-via-action-scriptalias-etc) for some overview.

For Apache 2.4.10+/[mod-proxy-fcgi](/questions/tagged/mod-proxy-fcgi) configs you *might* be able to use something like:

```
 AddHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php-fpm-usr123.sock|fcgi://localhost" .php
```

Or `SetHandler` with name mapping from your `.htaccess`. But again, consulting your hoster on the concrete FPM socket is unavoidable. There's no generic answer to this on modern PHP-FPM setups.

Comment: I tried to add this but there is no fpm sock file in that path so I am facing an error. I added multiple PHP and applied php80 for a particular folder but that's not working. globally ma has PHP 7.0 but for that application file, I configured 8.0. but the application loaded with 7.0 only.

Comment: Gotta check your `/etc/php/***/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` (or related configs) for the `listen=` directive, to figure out if there's a socket path, or a plain old port listener.

Answer (score 11):

To switch to PHP 4.4:

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php4 .php .php4 .php3`

To switch to PHP 5.0:

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .php5 .php4 .php3`

To switch to PHP 5.1:

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php51 .php .php5 .php4 .php3`

To switch to PHP 5.2:

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php .php5 .php4 .php3`

To switch to PHP 5.3:

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php .php5 .php4 .php3`

To switch to PHP 5.4:

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php .php5 .php4 .php3`

To switch to PHP 5.5:

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php .php5 .php4 .php3`

To switch to the secure PHP 5.2 with Suhosin patch:

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52s .php .php5 .php4 .php3`

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me

**PHP 7.2**

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php
```

**PHP 7.3**

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php
```

Comment: where we have to add this. can you tell the path and filename

Comment: You need to create a .htaccess file in the root folder of your website usually the same folder of your index page

Answer (score 5):

Try this to switch to php4:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php4 .php
```

Upd. Looks like I didn't understand your question correctly. This will not help if you have **only** php 4 on your server.

Answer (score 5):

just FYI in GoDaddy it's this:

> AddHandler x-httpd-php5-3 .php

Answer (score 3):

An addition to the current marked answer:

Place the addhandler inside the following scope, like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php
   RewriteEngine On

   ....

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

for php8 code generated by Cpanel:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php80 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

required PHP version should be installed

Answer (score 2):

Go to File Manager on your CPanel >>> Public html >>> find the .htaccess file >>> right click on the on it >>>> click edit.[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAKk0.png)

Type the number of the version you want to change to. i.e - 73, 70 or 71.

Hope this helps. After that, save changes.

Answer (score 2):

For CPanel users (as of May 2022, selecting PHP v8.1), use **Software -> "MultiPHP Manager"** modifies PHP versions *per subdomain*. it adds this to the subdomain's directory's .htaccess file:

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php81” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php81 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

If you don't see the PHP version you want in the select list, then install it via **WHM -> Software -> "EasyApache"**.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents here as this question is old, but I found myself needing an answer for a legacy site that supports PHP 5.6 at best.

Site is on Media Temple (which is now GoDaddy). I set the PHP version to 5.6 in cPanel but it wasn't taking on one of my sites. None of the above answers worked for me, but if you are running cPanel, adding this to the a site's individual .htaccess file seems to do the trick:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56___lsphp .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

If you're on cPanel now, chances are you are using Easy Apache v3 or 4, hence the "ea" part of the handler. This part I'm not sure about:

```
___lsphp
```

Any other combination of handlers from the above answers would just force a download on any page.

BTW, MultiPHP Manager isn't an option on my cPanel. I would guess this would add it for you per directory / site.

Here's where I pulled this from: https://www.gonlinesites.com/web-hosting-tips/how-to-add-handlers-to-change-php-version-in-cpanel-setup-php-version/

Answer (score -34):

You can't change PHP version by .htaccess.

you need to get your server updated, for PHP 5.3 or you can find another host, which serves PHP 5.3 on shared hosting.

Comment: ok, is there is any alter way to do it (with out upgrading or changing host server) ??

Comment: Does your application use any feature, that is very specific to PHP 5.3??

If not, running your application on the available host, won't be an issues, i guess.

if it is giving errors, then you have to get your host changed.

Comment: yes,some of the features are working with only php 5 or greater only

Comment: there's not way out mate.

you got to make the switch.

Comment: @ Sankalp Shekhar Ok, thanks a lot. I will contact my host provider.