# How do I specify Ansible PHP version?

Tags: php, ansible

How do I specify which version of PHP that Ansible loads up? Note: Ansible is software for managing the build of servers, you specify the recipe for how you want your server setup and then can fire up a new server in a few minutes. I am looking specifically for how to do this with "Ansible".

Comment: how many versions of php are you running?

Comment: Depends on the server and SAPI setup. Possible Duplicate of [how to change php version in htaccess in server](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12561203)

Comment: how is this a duplicate? I'm not talking about using htaccess. I am talking about firing up a server with Ansible. Ansible is software for managing servers and computers ( which is somewhat similar to Puppet or Chef). You specify in your playbook which settings you want and then you can fire up as many servers as you want. It is a valuable tool for server farm management and changing .htaccess is not an alternative way of doing this!!  To simplify "Ansible" manages a server whereas changing the .htaccess file is an internal change.

Comment: I would also like to know this, I'm using Ansible alongside Vagrant with a Ubuntu VM which appears to default to 5.3 when I need 5.4

Answer (score 1):

The version/s of PHP installed/available depends on your operating system and the repositories it has access to. If you're on a RHEL-based system, you might want to look at the [IUS Repository](http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/6/x86_64/repoview/letter_p.group.html) and install `php54` rather than the default `php`. I'm sure there are similar Debian repositories available.

Comment: okay thanks, I was wondering if it was possible to have multiple PP versions running so I could have some Ansible projects with PHP 5.3 and some with PHP 5.4 and not be tied down to what is available on the host machine.

Comment: Really puzzled by "I could have some Ansible projects with PHP 5.3 and some with PHP 5.4".

Comment: it is possible to have multiple php version running. You could switch the version in folder by htaccess or use an symfony webserver or what ever... there are severl ways