# How to switch between PHP versions using .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-proxy

So, I have a barebones VPS running CentOS 7, Apache 2.4, and various different versions of PHP-CGI with PHP-FPM.

I was able to use different PHP versions at once using multiple PHP-FPM servers running on different sockets, and handle requests by a specific server using mod_proxy's ProxyPassMatch directive. This allows me to use a specific version of PHP for one virtual host, and a different version of PHP for another virtual host with one Apache installation. The main drawback to this is I can only specify specific PHP versions by modifying server configuration files or virtual host files; not as a regular user through .htaccess.

All the shared hosting company's out there with cPanel (HostGator, Bluehost, Inmotion, etc...), allow you to change the PHP version in a specific directory using .htaccess AddHandlers. How can I do this on my own server? Is this a cPanel exclusive function?

The handlers they use are similar to this:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```

After a little research, I believe that these are actually custom MIME-type's that are being used as Handlers. These MIME types are obviously not a part of a vanilla Apache installation.

First of all, I'm not really sure what a MIME-type is. I assume it's similar to a handler. More importantly: how can I create MIME types like this that route traffic to a specific PHP binary and feed the output to Apache to be served to clients?

Does anybody know how to do this? I haven't found any information online.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They just use PHP as a CGI to run the various PHP versions and registering handlers to each version.  A basic explanation of how to do it can be found here: https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/apache/run-php-applications-under-cgi-with-apache-on-debian-5-lenny  `AddHandler` and `Action` are the primary directives involved in setting this up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change php version in htaccess in server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561203/how-to-change-php-version-in-htaccess-in-server)