# symfony 1.4 - change the version of PHP

Tags: php, wamp, symfony-1.4

I have 2 different PHP versions installed. When I try to run a task it runs with the default version of PHP. How can I change the version of PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change php version in htaccess in server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561203/how-to-change-php-version-in-htaccess-in-server)

Comment: The task will run with the PHP binary set in your user path. If you want to use another version you will have to use the full path to the PHP binary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the interpreter on command line:

```
$ /path/to/correct/php symfony the-task
```