# Can't access prestashop admin back office

Tags: prestashop

Unable to access Prestashop back office.

When using the URL obtain the back office get two errors through the console debug

GET http://currykit.co/zoombox/zoombox.css (index):27 
GET http://currykit.co/themes/theme547/css/grid_prestashop.css

Haven't changed anything but hosting service have upgraded from PHP5 v5.6 to PHP v7.0

Comment: Which version of prestashop are you using? have you checked if this version is compatible with php 7? Your hosting service upgraded the php version suddenly, without previous communication?

Comment: hi leo_ap,

You're correct, it's prestashop 1.5 which isn't compatible with PHP 7.0. Guess I'll be upgrading, I had 5 days notice that they were upgrading from the hosting service. Of course, I was away while they sent the communication

I shall upgrade Prestashop and upvote / close as solved if it works.

Answer (score 0):

By the comments:

If you encounter problems upgrading your store, try to contact your hosting support in order to discover if they provide an apache handler that permits you to run an specific version of php. Many hosts nowadays offer this resource and its very useful, you simply need to add a line in .htaccess file, like:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php
```

(see this post: [how to change php version in htaccess in server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561203/how-to-change-php-version-in-htaccess-in-server))

That way, your store your return to work normally.

Comment: Changing the php version just stops the scripts from working, then when trying to access the site just downloads the PHP file.

Comment: In that case, maybe you host doesn't offer such resource. Have you contacted them?

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who were wondering how the issue was fixed, It was the permissions of the files within the server that didn't have write access but only read access, therefore I could not access the back office.