# change php version using .htaccess in cpanel is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, version, cpanel

I am trying to change the php version in my server using htaccess. I am following this question's answer [how to change php version in htaccess in server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561203/how-to-change-php-version-in-htaccess-in-server)

 But did not work for me. When I entering my project, it's downloading a file.  Would someone help me to solve this issue, please? Here is by .htaccess bellow-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with cPanel. That depends entirely on how your hoster has setup PHP. Chances are they're using FCGIProxyPassMatch, not MIME handlers. (Also: `<IfModule>` begone!)

Comment: `php71` ? I think it should be `php7` if your host has php7 installed.

Comment: I have no 'Select PHP Version' option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally,  `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php` worked for me. Thank you!