# Need 2 PHP versions for using Drupal on LAMP

Tags: php, drupal, lamp

I need to run 2 different PHP versions (5.6 and 7) because of Drupal 6 & 8.
Actually I use a LAMP server Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP 5.6.
So these are my needs:

- How can I install 2 differents PHP versions ?
- How can I assign/choose a specific PHP version for each website depending on the drupal version ?

This for starting.

Thanks

Comment: I personally try to avoid to taint my system with project specific installations. A really nice alternative to installing PHP is to run it inside a docker container with XDebug enabled while mounting the working dir into it. But this takes a bit more time to setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP 5.6 security updates will end at the end of this year. Starting January 1st, PHP 5.6 is considered not secure. Before anything else, please consider migrating your Drupal 6 installation to PHP 7 instead of running a two tiered solution.

To find out more about why you shouldn't use PHP 5.6 under Drupal 6, see this 3rd-party announcement of PHP7 support: https://www.mydropwizard.com/blog/drupal-6-year-2020-and-php-7-support

If for some reason you still wish to run different versions of PHP, and are running mod-php, you can do so by specifying the version in the .htaccess file of each Drupal installation. Full details at [how to change php version in htaccess in server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561203/how-to-change-php-version-in-htaccess-in-server)

For the modern PHP-FPM setups, you'll likely need to set the version in the virtual hosts file...

Good luck on your mission!

Comment: thanks for this information, if I can use a Drupal 6 version compatible with PHP7, it will be better and easier for me.So I go to learn how to update php 5.6 to 7 on my lamp server.

Comment: after tried to use both version of PHP together, I can't 5.6 do work for D6. So I made 2 VM, one with 5.6 and other one with 7.2, 2 different  IP's, and each Drupal version get is dedicate PHP version