# Change PHP version on the server only on my site

Tags: php, .htaccess, version, php-7

I'm testing some php code on a test server of my company, but there are some importante things running on really old versions of php. My boss gave me a directory where I can test some code, but the code is in PHP7.

I told him I couldn't test because of php version, and he said the server had php7 installed on /opt/php-7.0/bin/php.

He told me to try this line on my index file:

```php
echo shell_exec('/opt/php-7.0/bin/php /home/something/yourscript.php')
```

It didn't work so I started to look for alternatives, like this link [how to change php version in htaccess in server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561203/how-to-change-php-version-in-htaccess-in-server) but I think I didn't understand because it looks simple but still not working. I don't want to ask my boss again to show I'm capable of doing things by myself, but I'm stuck at the moment.

Is there a way to change php version for a specific folder? Either in .htaccess of that folder or index.php file?

PS: My project is something like: http://example.com/my-project

Comment: That depends on how PHP is embedded in the web server in the first place - is it run as an Apache module, FastCGI, … See http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php for starters.

Comment: "It didn't work" does not help. Instead of trying numerous different things try to understand what the actual issue is and solve that. Using that `shell_exec` statement is possible, though highly unorthodox. So you want to find out why that does not work for you.

Comment: And by the way: why don't you simply develop and test on a another system? Use a docker container or a virtual machine or even install php and a http server on your native development system.