# Multiple PHP Version

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

I'm want to make a multiple php in my cpanel, i have a laravel apps and other sites (using wordpress).
My wordpress sites will not work if i'm using php version 7.3. The PHP version must 5.5 for my wordpress sites.

And then if the PHP version is 5.5 my app with laravel will not work and then showing 500 Error.

The suitable solution for my case is multiple PHP version with htaccess. Do you can give me a example code for multiple using htaccess? Because i'm using this code is not work for me

```
 <IfModule mime_module>
 AddHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php72___lsphp .php .php5 .phtml
 AddHandler application/x-httpd-php72 .php
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(php4|php5|php7|php3|php2|php|phtml)$">

 SetHandler application/x-lsphp73

 </FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines to your htaccess for multi php.

To switch to PHP 4.4:
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php4 .php

To switch to PHP 5.0:
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php

To switch to PHP 5.1:
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php51 .php

To switch to PHP 5.2:
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php

To switch to PHP 5.3:
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php

To switch to PHP 5.4:
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

To switch to PHP 5.5:
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php

To switch to PHP 5.6:
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php

To switch to PHP 7:
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php7 .php

To switch to PHP 7.1:
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php

[duplicate question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561203/how-to-change-php-version-in-htaccess-in-server)