# Setting specific PHP version with SetHandler in .htacess per directory doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu-18.04, php-7.3

Using Ubuntu 18 & Apache, I am trying to achieve state in which a PHP handler of my choice is used in each directory.

There is a .htaccess directive for that which itself works fine - I can change `x-httpd-php` to `x-httpd-php-source` and  it is correctly applied

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

So I thought I would set a specific one similary as in tutorials for AddHandler

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php73
</FilesMatch>
```

Sadly, this does nothing (raw PHP code is displayed)

I have PHP7.1 - PHP7.3 installed and modules are enabled with `sudo a2enmod php7.*`

**EDIT:** I was able to do this with `SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"` after some [extra package installing](https://tecadmin.net/install-multiple-php-version-apache-ubuntu/) , however I would like to know how to force PHP version during SetHandler in a way I described.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14750631/7406948 Check this one

Comment: @NemanjaJeremic that is using AddHandler, not SetHandler