# How Do I Set PHp Version Using Htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, version

i am getting the error in QUOTE:

> "Class 'Locale' not found [code: 0] Notice: Trying to access array
> offset on value of type null8"

Reason because i need php version 5.6 but hosting company only provides central php version for all sites and not for individual sites in their shared hosting plan...

how do i use .htaccess to set php version 5.6 for one of my domains  please help....

i have tried the codes below none of them are working

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php4|php5|php7|php3|php2|php|phtml)$">
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php56
</FilesMatch>

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php .php4 .php3

AddType application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```

Comment: Why do you think `Class 'Locale' not found` means you should be using a different version of PHP?

Comment: Because once i change the central php version to 5.6 the website starts working perfectly

Comment: Have you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561203/how-to-change-php-version-in-htaccess-in-server. Silly question but you are prefixing your code with `#`. You're not doing that in the actual .htaccess file, right?

Comment: And obligatory statement re: old PHP versions. You _really_ should get your code working on current PHP versions.

Comment: Sorry i just included the # here to state my point as in list of codes. not like it was in code sorry about that

Comment: i tried every available thing there and the best i got was that the website downloads a file containing the code in QUOTE when the website is loaded                                                                                   "<?php  include ('init.php');
  $router = new Router();
  $tpl = App::View(BASEPATH . 'view/');
  
  //admin routes
  $router->mount('/admin', function() use ($router, $tpl) {
      //admin login
   $router->match('GET|POST', '/login', function () use ($tpl)
   {
    if (App::Auth()->is_Admin()) {
     Url::redirect(SITEURL . '/admin/'); 
     exit;