# PHP update in WordPress without cPanel

Tags: php, wordpress, cloud, cpanel, updates

I am facing a problem with updating PHP in the website I am working on WordPress, as the hosting website does not provide cPanel or any control panel and the server is cloud

Also, I do not have enough information about the website because I did not create it.

I have contacted the hosting site. They said that I do not have a shared account with them, so they cannot check, Is there a solution other than changing the hosting site? I tried to search for the same problem as mine, but I still haven't found a solution.
PHP version: 7.0.8

Thanks

Comment: Your PHP version needs to be changed on the hosting directly so if you cant change that then you are in a bit of a picky situation. I would recommend trying to get direct access the the account which has the website under its hosting and see what you can do from there if no luck I would recommend moving hosting as it sounds like the support isnt the best from what you have said.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried to log in to the account, but the validity is very limited. I cannot manage the server, but I think I will change the hosting with a better hosting. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Providing the hosting company name and website url and your current hosting plan will help.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your hosting provider. Your hosting provider may use alternative product e.g. DirectAdmin, Plesk, etc. Some providers have custom management solutions in place, but may still provide a settings for PHP version selection.

You can also try to bump PHP version blindly through .htaccess (if enabled) and use phpinfo() to see if that worked. See discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561203/how-to-change-php-version-in-htaccess-in-server).

Comment: You are right, but I searched for any alternatives they offer and I did not find any, I also tried your way, but it did not work, so I will change the hosting, thank you for your help